# Data structure for clipping detection

Tags: data-structures, sdl, pygame, clipping

I'm using SDL (pygame) for a cnc simulator. Initally, screen refreshing is done using the painter's algorithm (just draw everything back-to-front) but it quicly becames slow with big surfaces.

To speed-up redrawing I'm only refreshing the parts of the screen that change at any given moment so if a numeric value changes its value, only its surface *and the correspondant sub-surface for every colliding surface* gets redrawn.

At the moment, im doing a clipping test over everything on on screen to detect the colliding surfaces, while significantly faster I think there should be a data structure and/or algorithm to avoid testing all the surfaces on screen.

Comment: The google term is "Z-plane hidden surface removal"

Comment: Are you using sprite groups?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to store the bounds of each of your surfaces. This will optimize your operation when finding the colliding surfaces.

You might find the [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981866/quadtree-for-2d-collision-detection) useful.