# Split a node in a Quadtree

Tags: algorithm, scala, quadtree

I'm implementing an immutable Quadtree in Scala and I can't understand what happens/when to split a node. These are my main references: [Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981866/quadtree-for-2d-collision-detection), [Article 2](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374) and a third one I can't find now.

I understand these 3 key points of a quadtree:

1. A node contains an object **in its subtree** if the object at least intersects the area covered by the node.
2. A Quadtree has a **maximum depth D** and the actual depth can be different for different branches
3. A leaf node can contain **a maximum of K objects before it splits** and becomes an intermediate node.

**Note:** objects are not points but they are 2D shapes.

My current implementation allows for intermediate nodes to hold objects but I want to simplify it and allow objects only on the leaves, but this raises a doubt.

Let's assume K=2. What happens if a have node that already contains 2 objects that covers most of its area and I add a 3rd big one one? The node splits into 4 children (point 3 above). All the 3 objects can intersect the children, so they are all moved to the each child (point 1 above). But now each child has to split and move the object to their children as they can hold only 2 objects and so on recursively.

This cycle continues indefinitely (which is bad) or until depth=D (point 2 above).

It doesn't look like having a full-depth tree just for 3 objects is a good thing. I end up with loads of pointers on many leaves to the same 3 objects and I have to scan the whole depth to look for collisions. And also insertion looks very costly.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: There might not be a problem with your understanding so much as your expectations.  Big objects are just a pain for many spatial data structures.

Comment: That's reassuring then. So it becomes a tradeoff with the parameter K. The more objects I can keep in a node the less this problem appear. How bad is keeping large object into intermediate nodes as I'm doing now? This surely solve that problem.