# Is there a method to test if UIViews intersect with one another?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I want to make a game in swift (xcode7) and I have a ball which may intersect with obstacles. But I've got different levels so I can't simply use `CGRectIntersectsWithCGRect`. Only if I use a switch, which would be the longest in the world and wouldn't look that nice..

So in my head I've a method like this:

```
ball.intersectsWithRect()->CGRect
```

or:
`CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, /*anyframe / anyview.frame*/)`

But I couldn't find anything like this. Is that even possible? Or is there even a simpler way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with looping through all your obstacles (keep them in an array, or loop through subviews) and using `CGRectIntersectsWithCGRect`?

Comment: A more specific explanation of your problem will probably get you better answers. There are a number of techniques commonly used for efficient hit detection but it's hard to know which if any would help you. One place to start might be with `quadtree`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981866/quadtree-for-2d-collision-detection