# iPhone - Detect collision of multiple buttons

Tags: iphone, ios5, collision-detection, accelerometer

I've just started to develop in iPhone and I've managed to make my buttons (six of them) to move with UIAccelerator. Problem I'm facing when they are colliding with each other. I want them to bounce back the same direction, and this works if I only use 2 buttons. But when there are multiple collisions with more than 2 buttons, they get overlapped and finally merged into each other.

Here's my code to set delegate itself:

```
UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.delegate = self;
accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
```

Delegate method of accelerator:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{
delta.x = acceleration.x * 5;
delta.y = acceleration.y * -5;

self.firstButton.center = CGPointMake(self.firstButton.center.x + delta.x, self.firstButton.center.y + delta.y);
self.secondButton.center = CGPointMake(self.secondButton.center.x + delta.x, self.secondButton.center.y + delta.y);
self.thirdButton.center = CGPointMake(self.thirdButton.center.x + delta.x, self.thirdButton.center.y + delta.y);
self.fourthButton.center = CGPointMake(self.fourthButton.center.x + delta.x, self.fourthButton.center.y + delta.y);
self.fifthButton.center = CGPointMake(self.fifthButton.center.x + delta.x, self.fifthButton.center.y + delta.y);
self.sixthButton.center = CGPointMake(self.sixthButton.center.x + delta.x, self.sixthButton.center.y + delta.y);

[self updateMovingObjects:self.firstButton];
[self updateMovingObjects:self.secondButton];
[self updateMovingObjects:self.thirdButton];
[self updateMovingObjects:self.fourthButton];
[self updateMovingObjects:self.fifthButton];
[self updateMovingObjects:self.sixthButton];
}
```

updateMovingObjects:

```
- (void)updateMovingObjects:(UIButton *)button{
/*** DETECT COLLISIONS ***/

// Right screen
if(button.center.x < button.frame.size.width / 2){
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.frame.size.width / 2, button.center.y); 
}
// Left screen
if(button.center.x > 320 - button.frame.size.width / 2){
    button.center = CGPointMake(320 - button.frame.size.width / 2, button.center.y); 
}
// Top screen
if(button.center.y < button.frame.size.height / 2){
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x, button.frame.size.height / 2); 
}
// Bottom screen
if(button.center.y > 480 - 20 - 43 - button.frame.size.height / 2){
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x, 480 - 20 - 43 - button.frame.size.height / 2); 
}

// Detect collision with objects
for (UIView *anotherView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (button == anotherView){
        continue;
    }
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, anotherView.frame)){
        float_t vec = sqrtf(powf(delta.x, 2.0)+powf(delta.y, 2.0));
        // collided from left or bottom
        if( (button.center.x + button.frame.size.width / 2 >= anotherView.center.x - anotherView.frame.size.width / 2 &&
             button.center.x + button.frame.size.width / 2 <= anotherView.center.x - anotherView.frame.size.width / 2 + 15)
           ||  (button.center.y - button.frame.size.height / 2 <= anotherView.center.y + anotherView.frame.size.height / 2 &&
                button.center.y - button.frame.size.height / 2 >= anotherView.center.y + anotherView.frame.size.height / 2 - 15) ){
               button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x - vec, button.center.y + vec);
           }
        // collided from top or right
        else{
            button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + vec, button.center.y - vec);
        }
    }
}

/*** END DETECT COLLISIONS ***/
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I made for functions which detects if it was collided from left, right, bottom or top. And works much better now, but problem still remains with overlapping if I have them all at once moving, my guess is that it doesn't have the time calculate and thus get overlapped:

```
- (BOOL)collidedFromLeft:(UIButton *)button{
for (UIView *anotherView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (button == anotherView){
        continue;
    }
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, anotherView.frame)){
        if(button.center.x + button.frame.size.width / 2 - delta.x < anotherView.center.x - anotherView.frame.size.width / 2 &&
           button.center.x + button.frame.size.width / 2 >= anotherView.center.x - anotherView.frame.size.width / 2){
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
return NO;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)collidedFromTop:(UIButton *)button{
for (UIView *anotherView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (button == anotherView){
        continue;
    }
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, anotherView.frame)){
        if(button.center.y + button.frame.size.height / 2 - delta.y < anotherView.center.y - anotherView.frame.size.height / 2 &&
           button.center.y + button.frame.size.height / 2 >= anotherView.center.y - anotherView.frame.size.height / 2){
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
return NO;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)collidedFromRight:(UIButton *)button{
for (UIView *anotherView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (button == anotherView){
        continue;
    }
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, anotherView.frame)){
        if(button.center.x - button.frame.size.width / 2 - delta.x > anotherView.center.x + anotherView.frame.size.width / 2 &&
           button.center.x - button.frame.size.width / 2 <= anotherView.center.x + anotherView.frame.size.width / 2){
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
return NO;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)collidedFromBottom:(UIButton *)button{
for (UIView *anotherView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (button == anotherView){
        continue;
    }
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, anotherView.frame)){
        if(button.center.y - button.frame.size.height / 2 - delta.y > anotherView.center.y + anotherView.frame.size.height / 2 &&
           button.center.x - button.frame.size.width / 2 <= anotherView.center.y + anotherView.frame.size.height / 2){
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
return NO;
```

}

Then I check while they are moving:

```
if([self collidedFromLeft:button]){
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x - 20, button.center.y);
}
if([self collidedFromRight:button]){
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + 20, button.center.y);
}
if([self collidedFromTop:button]){
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x, button.center.y - 20);
}
if([self collidedFromBottom:button]){
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x, button.center.y + 20);
}
```

Comment: That's quite dangerous code you have, as i understand you want to call `updateMovingObjects` to make sure the argument button is not overlapped with other buttons, but in general while resolving the overlays of `button1` you can make other overlays with buttons: with `button2` resolving `button3`, with `button2-3` resolving `button4` and so on. And while growing, the overlay-delta might grow over 15px this way.

Comment: Yeah I notice there's some leak in my code. I've searched every to find some examples to use in my situation, but can't find any =(

Comment: The best approach i was able to find is the quadtree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434335/quadtree-for-2d-collision-detection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981866/quadtree-for-2d-collision-detection You might want to check the basics of 2D collisions detect http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection and Quadtree itself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree Unfortunately, i'm not able to answer your question or to give a better guideline, please update your status in the future.